# how to remove the error showing below:(laravel framework)

Tags: php, laravel-4.2

I have viewed a lot off documents already. I am trying to do my login, but its not working. Showing errors. I don't know the reason.i am very new in laravel

This is my controller code

```
    public function do_login()
    {
        $credentials = [
        'username'=>Input::get('username'),
        'password'=>Input::get('password')
    ]; 
    $rules = [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password'=>'required'
    ];

    //validating the credentials.
    $validator = Validator::make($credentials,$rules);

    //in case the credentials are valid. Try to login the user.
    if($validator->passes())
    {
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
            //if successfull redirect the user 
            return Redirect::to('home');
        }
        else
        {
            //else send back the login failure message.
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('failure','username or password is invalid!');
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        //send back the validation errors.
         return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

}
```

this is my model code:

```
    <?php namespace LARAVEL\laravel_1st_project\models\UserModel;

    use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class UserModel extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface , RemindableInterface
    {
        public $table = "user";
        protected $primaryKey = 'employee_id';

        //public $timestamps = false;
    }
```

this is my app\config\auth.php :

```
  'model' => 'LARAVEL\laravel_1st_project\UserModel',   

  'table' => 'user',

'reminder' => array(

    'email' => 'email.auth.reminder',

    'table' => 'password_reminders',

    'expire' => 60,

),
```

Error :
  [image: & finally this is the error um still facing]

Comment: Your `UserModel` must implement the interface `\Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface`, which it doesn't seem to be doing

Comment: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/11/changing-your-authentication-model check this one, make sure your USER implements UserInterface

Comment: where to change my code or what code do i need to add?thats what a fresher faces.... :(

Comment: You got a link with all the info from @minhhn2910

Comment: `<?php namespace LARAVEL\laravel_1st_project\public\UserModel;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
this is my UserModel:
class UserModel extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    public $table = "user";
 protected $primaryKey = 'employee_id';

 //public $timestamps = false;
}`
config/auth.php :   'model' => 'LARAVEL\laravel_1st_project\public\UserModel',
but its nt working still.....

Comment: @SaifurRahman: So what is the error message after you do that, can you update your question?

Comment: @minhhn2910  this is all details ....

Comment: I think php cannot find your UserModel definition, it's the problem of namespace & env. Can you make it simple first, since we dont have information about your configuration & directory skeleton: place the code for class usermodel in `app/UserModel.php` then in your `app\config\auth.php` you change model conf to this : `'model' => 'App\UserModel::class',`

Comment: u are trying for my solution,thank u so much for that.i have tried according to ur instruction.but its now showing that->    `Class \App\UserModel::class not found`  @minhhn2910